# Non repeating number from a range and submitting from a form to a page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can I please get some help with this please?

I'm needing to select a non repeated random number from a range of 1 - 80 but not repeat it.
Rather then my form getting the range from the user I wish to define it in the java script and at the press of submit button it generates a non repeated number in the range of 1 - 80 in the text area like the form like this with a submit, clear and result text area.

Here is my form code:

```
<form name="generate">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input TYPE="button" name="send_it" VALUE="ENTER" onClick="chooseRandom(this.form)">&nbsp; &nbsp; <input TYPE="reset" VALUE="CLEAR" onClick="clearForm(this.form)"><br />
      <br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Random Number:&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input TYPE="text" NAME="result" SIZE="5"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function chooseRandom(form) {

var m = parseInt(form.lower.value);

var n = parseInt(form.upper.value) - m;

var output = Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + m;
        if (m < 0) {
            alert('Enter # greater than 0');
        }
        if (n > 79) {
            alert('Enter # less than 80');
        }

form.result.value = output;

}
// Clears the form

function clearForm(form) {

    form.upper.value="";

    form.lower.value="";

    form.upper.focus();

    form.upper.select();

}
</script>
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by non repeated. In what context? Please provide more details regarding this.

Comment: So I have a range of 1 - 80 and my java script when clicking on submit it picks a number from that range I do not wish to repeat that number in the browser session.

Comment: It picks 5 out of 1 -80 I don't want to pick that again in the current browser session. Unless I refresh the page or restart browser.

Comment: OK. But when you submit then form in a standard way what will happen is actually a page refresh. Is using ajax to post data an option? This will allow you to keep track of numbers used.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this is what you wanted :) I am new at answering questions here.

```
var rand = [];

for(var i = 1;i<=80;i++){
    rand.push(i);
}
function getRand(){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)
    return rand.splice(index,1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You will have to use ajax to post the form in order to not do a page refresh which reset "usedNumbers".

```
<form id="generate" name="generate">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="send_it" value="ENTER" onclick="chooseRandom(this.form)">&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" onclick="clearForm(this.form)">
          <br />
          <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Random Number:&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input TYPE="text" NAME="result" SIZE="5"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and

```
<script>
function chooseRandom(form) {
    form.result.value = getNonRepeatingRandomNumberWithinRange();

    // Do ajax based post thereby preventing page refresh
}

var usedNumbers = [],
    min = 1,
    max = 80;

function getNonRepeatingRandomNumberWithinRange() {
    // Generate random number within range
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

    // If number already used, try again (if all slots are used we return the number anyway)
    if (contains(usedNumbers, num) && usedNumbers.length < max)
        return getRand();

    // Store number and return as value
    return usedNumbers[usedNumbers.length - 1] = num;
}

// Helper function for determining if an array contains value
function contains(arr, obj) {
    var i = arr.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (arr[i] === obj)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```